# Flutter Syncfusion range pointer SweepGradient gradient colours

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, gauge, radial

I am trying to apply gradient colors to my range pointer, but it is not the result I want. This is my current result.

**Current result:**

[image]

What I want is that when the range pointer is in the range of -20 to 40, the range pointer gradient colour should be in the shade of green and not show the red tip.

The code below is the code I'm using to display the gradient colours on my range pointer. Can anyone let me know if this is the package issue or I'm missing something out? Thank you.

```
RangePointer(value: 20, width: 12, enableAnimation: true,
  pointerOffset: -16, cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve, sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.logicalPixel,
  gradient: SweepGradient(
    colors: < Color > [Color(0xFF51888e),
      Color(0xFF66a86d),
      Color(0xFFd5d688),
      Color(0xFFdd9d6d),
      Color(0xFFd05c50),
    ], stops: < double > [
      0,
      0.25,
      0.5,
      0.75,
      1
    ]
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion range pointers will apply all gradient colors across the range pointer and there is currently no option to visualize the gradient colors based on the range value.